# Translate operation is rotating?

Tags: opengl, matrix

```
cube
 [[ 1.  0.  0. 6.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]]

view
[[1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]]

final
[[ 1.  0.  0. 6.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]]
```

Hello! I have a cube and I'm trying to move it around. The above are the calculated matricies for the cube, viewport, and the combined matrix after multiplication. The result is this:

[image]

I'm not sure why it's being warped like this instead of scooting over a bit. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your matrix is row major, so you should transpose it in order to get behaviour you expect, since OpenGL memory layout is more column-major friendly, because translation is located in the memory at the fourth vector of the 4x4 matrix.

Comment: You're a legend, can't believe I didn't think to try that.